# open a bootstrap modal with a specific HIDDEN TAB(without nav-tabs ) by jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This modal box has no visible tab. I just use *href attribute* for navigate to other pages.

```
<div id="bootmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="370" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: none;">
    <div class="tab-content">

    <!--
        NOTE: i'll not use nav-tab
        ===========================
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs col-md-3 custom-bullet">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login_tab">Login</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lostpass_tab">Lost Your Password?</a></li>
        </ul>
    -->

        <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="login_tab">
            <form id="login" action="login" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#lostpass_tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label label-info pull-left"><?php _e('Lost your password?','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                    <?php if (get_option( 'users_can_register' ) != true): ?>
                        <a href="#register_tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php _e('Registration is disable rightn now!','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="#register_tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php _e('Create a New Account.','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php if (get_option( 'users_can_register' ) == true): ?>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="register_tab">
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="lostpass_tab">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to open specific hidden tab by using

```
<button type="button" id="wp-ajax-logout" class="btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal">Login</button>
<button type="button" id="wp-ajax-lost-pass" class="btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal">Lost your password</button>
```

or by a tag

```
<a href="#login_tab" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal" >Register</a>
<a href="#lostpass_tab" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal" >Register</a>
```

**Is there any way to open specific hidden tabs by using jquery?**

**EDIT:**

I want to use the trigger `<button>Register</button>` or `<a href="#login_tab">Login</a>` from **page template** by using shortcode function.

I find some code in around website's. They use js.

```
$("#bootmodal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var tab = e.relatedTarget.hash;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="'+tab+'"]').tab('show')
})
```

In here they use `.nav-tabs`, but i don't want. Without that issue everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can open specific hidden tabs by using jquery. i have created demo you can take reference from below snippet of code.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tab-controllers">
      <li class="active"><a id="login_tab_btn" class="btn active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal"  >Login</a></li>
      <li><a id="lostpass_tab_btn" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal" >Lost Your Password?</a></li>
      <li><a id="register_tab_btn" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal">Register</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="bootmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="370" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: none;">
    <div class="tab-content">


        <div class="tab-pane active" id="login_tab">
            <form id="login" action="login" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header"> <h2>Login tab Content</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                 <a href="#lostpass_tab_btn"><span class="label label-info pull-left"><?php _e('Lost your password?','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                <?php if (get_option( 'users_can_register' ) != true): ?>
                    <a href="#register_tab_btn"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php _e('Registration is disable rightn now!','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                <a href="#register_tab_btn"><span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php _e('Create a New Account.','woocomputers'); ?></span></a>
                <?php endif; ?>                          
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php if (get_option( 'users_can_register' ) == true): ?>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="register_tab">
               <div class="modal-header"> <h2>register tab Content</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                     </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="lostpass_tab">
          <div class="modal-header"><h2>Lost Password tab Content</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                    
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

jQuery('#login_tab').show();
jQuery('#register_tab').hide();
jQuery('#lostpass_tab').hide();

jQuery(document).on('click', '#login_tab_btn', function() {
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li a").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    jQuery('#register_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#lostpass_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#login_tab').show();
});
 jQuery(document).on('click', '#lostpass_tab_btn', function() {
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li a").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    jQuery('#login_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#register_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#lostpass_tab').show();
});
 jQuery(document).on('click', '#register_tab_btn', function() {
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".tab-controllers li a").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    jQuery('#login_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#lostpass_tab').hide();
    jQuery('#register_tab').show();
});
});
```

Let me know if this helps to you!

Comment: you use `tab-controllers` class, but i don't want to use it inside the modal. The trigger will be inside my page template file. I find some code from several website. I'll edit my question again. Please try to give me right answer.

Comment: you can also use "tab-controller" div outside of model. i have update my answer. on click specific link it will show that container. let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @ Chetan Vaghela, thank you very much, everything is working fine. But now the problem is, i can't use `.modal-footer` **class link's** after i use your jquery codes  _(see my login form's `.modal-footer` class links)_. Is there any way to use link's to go one form to another form **(login to register or lost password form)**.

Comment: @ Chetan Vaghela, i am waiting for your answer. Please someone help me.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. i have update my answer and add links in .modal-footer class. please check now. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Don't mind bro @Chetan Vaghela. Actually i can't detect your new updated code. Can you tell me where is the new change?

Comment: in login model HTML section, model footer section.